# What is the universality class of transition in one-dimensional XXZ Heisenberg at $\Delta$ = -1?

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models

In the one-dimensional spin-$\frac12$  XXZ  Heisenberg model, 
$$H=J\sum_i{S_i^x S_{i+1}^x + S_i^y S_{i+1}^y+\Delta S_i^z S_{i+1}^z},$$
with $J>0$. There are two transition points:

- $\Delta=1$
- $\Delta=-1$

The transition at $\Delta=1$ is of BKT type. What about the transition at $\Delta=-1$? Could anyone provide some reference?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Franchini's lecture notes](https://people.sissa.it/~ffranchi/BAnotes.pdf) on the Bethe Ansatz techniques useful. Chapter four is relevant for your question I would say.